# Why does iOS NSLocale localeIdentifier return "zh-Hans_US" (with hyphen AND underscore)?

Tags: ios, localization, nslocale

I changed my language setting to Chinese Simplified and then checked my `[[NSLocale currentLocale] localeIdentifier]`. It was "zh-Hans_US". I understand that zh specifies Chinese, Hans indicates the simplified version, and US indicates that I'm the US so it should use that regional variation, but *why* does it use a hyphen first and then an underscore?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The underscore separates the language from the region. The hyphen separates the language into the base language and its dialect or script.

zh-Hans is the language (Chinese and the Hans script) and US is the region.

See Apple's docs for more details: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/LanguageandLocaleIDs/LanguageandLocaleIDs.html

Comment: will it return different region when I open application from India or Australia?

Comment: I don't believe this documentation to be correct anymore and is now labeled as "Archive". MacOS and iOS returns underscored such as `zh_Hans_HK` while the localization .strings file that Xcode creates is hyphenated such as `zh-Hans-HK`. Locale.availableIdentifiers returns underscored.

Comment: The link content has been archived, is this answer still relevant today? I found 2 links that can tell us what the new format is: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/choosing-localization-regions-and-scripts, and https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/locale.

Comment: I don't think that's what `Locale.current.identifier` will return at least as of iOS 15. It doesn't use Hans or Hant in my testing at all, and will return `zh_CN` for Chinese Simplified (region: China mainland), `zh_HK` for Traditional Chinese (region: Hong Kong), `zh-CN_HK` for Simplified Chinese (region: Hong Kong) and `zh-HK_CN` for Traditional Chinese (region: China mainland). Other regions will be appended in a similar way.